# Alert message not showing up in slack using prometheus and alertmanager

Tags: docker-compose, alert, monitoring, prometheus

I am trying to get  the **alert** found by Prometheus to be notified in slack using **alertmanager**.

*This is the **alert.rules** file and is working fine*

```
groups:
- name: Instances
  rules:
  # Alert for any instance that is unreachable for >5 minutes.
  - alert: InstanceDown
    expr: up == 0
    for: 5m
    labels:
      severity: page
    # Prometheus templates apply here in the annotation and label fields of the alert.
    annotations:
      description: '{{ $labels.instance }} of job {{ $labels.job }} has been down for more than 5 minutes.'
      summary: 'Instance {{ $labels.instance }} down'
```

It is showing the one instance down successfully.
[image]

But What is the problem in my **alertmanager.yml** that it is not sending the notifications  to slack. I have also setup the slack webhook successfully and have even tested if the hook is working fine while created a hook with the service that is provided by the slack

***alertmanager.yml***

```
groups:
- name: Instances
  rules:
  # Alert for any instance that is unreachable for >5 minutes.
  - alert: InstanceDown
    expr: up == 0
    for: 5m
    labels:
      severity: page
    # Prometheus templates apply here in the annotation and label fields of the alert.
    annotations:
      description: '{{ $labels.instance }} of job {{ $labels.job }} has been down for more than 5 minutes.'
      summary: 'Instance {{ $labels.instance }} down'
[tgurung@ip131 prometheus_graphana_myversion]$ cat alertmanager/alertmanager.yml 


route: 
  receiver: 'slack-notifications'
  #group_by: [alertname, datacenter, app]

receivers:
- name: 'slack-notifications'
  slack_configs:
  - api_url: https://hooks.slack.com/services/T52GRFN3F/B93KTCUHH/JC
    channel: #general
    send_resolved: true

    # Alertmanager templates apply here.
    text: "<!channel> \nsummary: {{ .CommonAnnotations.summary }}\ndescription: {{ .CommonAnnotations.description }}"
```

[image]

**When running docker-compose up I get following**

```
prometheus_1     | level=error ts=2018-02-06T09:36:35.580565429Z caller=notifier.go:454 component=notifier alertmanager=http://x.x.x.x:9093/api/v1/alerts count=0 msg="Error sending alert" err="Post http://x.X.x.x:9093/api/v1/alerts: dial tcp x.x.x.x:9093: getsockopt: no route to host"
```

***Solving above error:***
To solve the above routing issues I ran the alertmanager in completely new instance and than that error is overcome

**Going to the API links in the error message I can see this**

```
{"status":"success","data":[]}
```

***And this is of alert_manager and looks working great.***

```
alertmanager_1   | level=info ts=2018-02-06T09:36:37.66654544Z caller=main.go:141 msg="Starting Alertmanager" version="(version=0.13.0, branch=HEAD, revision=fb713f6d8239b57c646cae30f78e8b4b8861a1aa)"
alertmanager_1   | level=info ts=2018-02-06T09:36:37.66661402Z caller=main.go:142 build_context="(go=go1.9.2, user=root@d83981af1d3d, date=20180112-10:32:46)"
alertmanager_1   | level=info ts=2018-02-06T09:36:37.668103448Z caller=main.go:279 msg="Loading configuration file" file=/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml
alertmanager_1   | level=info ts=2018-02-06T09:36:37.673288146Z caller=main.go:354 msg=Listening address=:9093
```

***Here is the prometheus.yml config file***

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 5s
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'my-monitor'

#alerting rules file
rule_files:
  - '/alertmanager/alert.rules'


scrape_configs:
    - job_name: 'prometheus'
      static_configs: 
       - targets: ['localhost:9090']

    - job_name: 'node-exporter'
      static_configs:
        - targets: ['node-exporter:9100']


alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
      - targets: ["54.36.X.X:9093"]  #this is the alertmanager service url
```

***Here is my docker-compose.yml***

```
version: '2'
volumes:
    grafana_data: {}

services:
    prometheus:
        image: prom/prometheus
        privileged: true
        volumes:
            - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
            - ./alertmanager/alert.rules:/alertmanager/alert.rules
            - ./alertmanager/alertmanager.yml:/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml
        command:
            - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
        ports:
            - '9090:9090'
        links:
            - "alertmanager"


    node-exporter:
        image: prom/node-exporter
        ports:
            - '9100:9100'

    alertmanager:
        image: prom/alertmanager
        privileged: true
        volumes:
            - ./alertmanager/alertmanager.yml:/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml
        command:
            - '--config.file=/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml'
        ports:
            - '9093:9093'
```

***The alertmanager status link does not show the config being passed from volume in docker-composer. It's showing default configs***

[image]

Comment: Your last screenshot shows no alerts on alertmanager, so this is not a problem with slack. Does the `/status` endpoint on prometheus show an entry for alertmanager?

Comment: You shouldn't need to duplicate your alert definition in the alertmanager config. The AM doesn't evaluate alerts, it merely forwards them. Also you shouldn't include any Slack Webhook URLs in public places like this.

Comment: @Marc yes it is showing up there as endpoints

Comment: BTW where should i load the alertmanager.yml configuration file. I have added it as `command: --config.file=/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml'` in docker-compose

Comment: @tex has a point though, the alert does not go into the alertmanager config. Does this even parse? I recommend you run prometheus and alertmanager locally to make sure your configuration is correct, then move it into docker.

Comment: This is the error message `firing:true
state:"alerting"
conditionEvals:" = true"
timeMs:"2.881ms"
error:"tsdb.HandleRequest() error Get http://54.X.X.X:9090/api/v1/query_range?end=2018-02-05T10%3A11%3A39.269636463Z&query=sum+%28+irate%28node_cpu%7Bmode%21%3D%27idle%27%2Cinstance%3D~%22%24server%3A.%2A%22%7D%5B5m%5D%29%29&start=2018-02-05T10%3A06%3A39.269636463Z&step=30.000: dial tcp X.X.X.X:9090: getsockopt: no route to host"` I get when testing it manually on grafana

Comment: I'm not sure what grafana has to do with it, instead check the alertmanager status pages to make sure it properly loaded the config, make sure prometheus points to alertmanager, and try a single alert. Then check the logs to see what happens.

Comment: can u just send plain text first insted of using variable in text like .CommonAnnotations.summary. i have faced it long time back because some variable was not working in text field
and can u put the alertmanager or prometheus logs here

Comment: @Deepak I have added the plain text and updated the question with the logs message when running docker-cmpose. Looks like prometheus is not able to connect to alertmanager

Comment: Shouldn't `- targets: ["54.36.X.X:9093"] ` be `- targets: ["alertmanager:9093"]` ?

Comment: Can you verify the config file is mounted e.g. `docker exec -it alertmanager cat /alertmanager/alertmanager.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

As some people have already pointed out, alertmanager configuration only includes how to send alerts and NOT to create alerts. That's prometheus' job.
Take a look at this repo, which sets prometheus with alertmanager very simply

https://github.com/stefanprodan/dockprom